# PHP: remove all anchor tags except anchors that are in figcaption tag

Tags: php, regex

Here is where I test my **regex** -> http://www.regexr.com/3ehda

I have tried with this pattern `<a.*>*?<\/a>`, but it doesn't catch it if it has new line(s) and it catches anchors that are in `figcaption`.

Can anyone help me with removing all anchor tags except anchors that are in `figcaption` tag?

If it's hard to do with **regex**, maybe, someone can give me a hint how can it be solved other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read it everywhere, regexes are not a reliable way to parse html (that contains too many traps). PHP has classes to parse, query and edit html strings:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
# prevent errors for badly formatted html to be displayed and store them
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
# parse the html content wrapped in a root tag with an xml declaration to specify
# the encoding, and build the DOM tree
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8"?><div>' . $html . '<\div>', LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
# clear the html errors
libxml_clear_errors();

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodeList = $xp->query('//a[not(./ancestor::figcaption)]');

# remove the selected nodes
foreach($nodeList as $node) {
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}

# build the result string concatenating root child nodes
$result = '';

foreach($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $childNode) {
    $result .= $dom->saveHTML($childNode);
}

echo $result;
```